# What is the difference between more, further, and additional?

Tags: differences, synonyms

Is there a difference between:

- "For **more** information, please contact..."
- "For **further** information, please contact..."
- "For **additional** information, please contact..."

If there is a difference, what is the difference?

Thanks

Comment: What did your dictionary or dictionaries tell you?  I'd say start there.

Comment: As far as I understand it, the basic message from the dictionary is that the words are synonymous but context is everything and dictionary isn't really going to pick up on that.

Answer (score 3):

In this specific case, there is no difference between the words.

In terms of how professional they sound, **further** and **additional** both sound significantly better than **more**.

All of this is, however, a matter of taste and style.

Answer (score -1):

If "further" and "additional" sound "significantly better," it's only because they satisfy clichés and the belief that extra syllables = elegance or intelligence, when really they add nothing but bombast. In conversation you would never say "for further" or "for additional information." Spoken, those phrases seem pretentious. Because they are.